# Chart JS - Use time for xAxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, chart.js

i added this code

```
scales: 
{
        xAxes: 
        [{
            type: 'time',
            time: 
            {
                unit: 'month',
                displayFormats: { month: 'MM' },
                max: '2017-10-09 18:43:53',
                min: '2017-10-02 18:43:53'
            }
        }]
},
```

to the options but it does not work. Any ideas what i'm making wrong?

**FIDDLE ->** 
https://jsfiddle.net/o473y9pw/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o473y9pw/ - doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you wish to use time for x-axis, your **`labels`** array should be an array of date/time string (`labels` array is correspondent to x-axis).

You would also need to set the [**`parser`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser) property *(to parse the date/time correctly)*, and x-axis' [ticks source](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source) to **`data`** *(to properly generate x-axis ticks)*.

**UPDATE**

If you only have a min and max date then, you can create a nice little [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) to populate the `labels` *(date)* array dynamically, as such :

```
plugins: [{
   beforeInit: function(chart) {
      var time = chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time, // 'time' object reference
         // difference (in days) between min and max date
         timeDiff = moment(time.max).diff(moment(time.min), 'd');
      // populate 'labels' array
      // (create a date string for each date between min and max, inclusive)
      for (i = 0; i <= timeDiff; i++) {
         var _label = moment(time.min).add(i, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
         chart.data.labels.push(_label);
      }
   }
}]
```

<sup>**note:** [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is used to make calculations easier.</sup>

[**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**](https://jsfiddle.net/sug6mdk3/) ⧩
<sup>( for demonstration purposes, I've changed the time `unit` to `day` )</sup>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   new Chart(document.getElementById("chartBox"), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
         datasets: [{
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 32, 15],
            label: "",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false,
            pointRadius: 0
         }]
      },
      options: {
         scales: {
            xAxes: [{
               type: 'time',
               time: {
                  parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                  unit: 'day',
                  displayFormats: {
                     day: 'ddd'
                  },
                  min: '2017-10-02 18:43:53',
                  max: '2017-10-09 18:43:53'
               },
               ticks: {
                  source: 'data'
               }
            }]
         },
         legend: {
            display: false
         },
         animation: {
            duration: 0,
         },
         hover: {
            animationDuration: 0,
         },
         responsiveAnimationDuration: 0
      },
      plugins: [{
         beforeInit: function(chart) {
            var time = chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time, // 'time' object reference
               timeDiff = moment(time.max).diff(moment(time.min), 'd'); // difference (in days) between min and max date
            // populate 'labels' array
            // (create a date string for each date between min and max, inclusive)
            for (i = 0; i <= timeDiff; i++) {
               var _label = moment(time.min).add(i, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
               chart.data.labels.push(_label);
            }
         }
      }]
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="chartBox"></canvas>
```

Comment: The problem is that i only have a min and max date. Do you know a nice solution to convert the min/max to a "date array"? Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Yes.. check updated answer. However, one thing to note that, in your fiddle you have more data than the number of dates *(diff between min and max)*.. that's unexpected. You should always have to have the same number of data as the dates, not more or less.

Comment: That is not good :/ ... any idea for a workaround? Maybee count the data array() and than create the dates (double)? I know that chartjs not shows every date when there are to many dates and not enough space. The Problem is that i need all data (if not, the chart is not accurate enough :(

Comment: What you're trying to do is a workaround in itself, that's not how chart.js works.. anyway, you can simply just increase the date range *(min/max)* depending on your data.. check [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/sug6mdk3/1/)

Answer (score 7):

The dataset should be an array of objects with properties x for time and y for value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      x: new moment().add(-10, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
    {
      x: new moment().add(-8, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
    {
      x: new moment().add(-6, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
    {
      x: new moment().add(-4, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
    {
      x: new moment().add(-2, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
    {
      x: new moment().add(-0, "months"),
      y: Math.random() * 100
    },
  ];

  new Chart(document.getElementById("chartBox"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        data: data,
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time'
        }]
      },
      legend: false
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="chartBox"></canvas>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o473y9pw/1/)

Comment: Thanks for simple example.  Most docs and examples are really convoluted and poor

Answer (score 3):

If the **xAxis label is in date format** use this code

```
time: 
     {
         format: 'MM',
         unit: 'month',
         displayFormats: { month: 'MM' },
         max: '2017-10-09 18:43:53',
         min: '2017-10-02 18:43:53'
     }
```

If the **xAxis label is as what u used numerals** use

```
 time:
      {
         format: 'MM',
         unit: 'month',
         parser:'MM',
         displayFormats: { month: 'MM' },
         max: '2017-10-09 18:43:53',
         min: '2017-00-02 18:43:53'
      }
```

Comment: Did not work, can you please give me an FIDDLE  example?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change a few things.

1. Your data should include **time** data.
2. If you set scale unit to be `month`, your min max should be more than one month to see the actual scales.

Here's simplified working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/f2xmkkao/